# upstart on ec2 does not update configs

Tags: amazon-ec2, upstart

changing Upstart services config files on EC2 servers does not cause Upstart to reload them. I guess it's due to the network nature of EC2's fs. what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `initctl reload-configuration` after modifying an Upstart service config file.